# Not a valid Month Error while Inserting timestamp value '2021-08-31T16:30:01.850'

Tags: sql, oracle

Getting error while inserting timestamp value '2021-08-31T16:30:01.850'

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Account_Master (Account_ID, Verified_Date) 
VALUES (1, '2021-08-31T16:30:01.850')
```

Table definition :

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_Account_Master 
(
    Account_ID Number(10) NOT NULL,
    Verified_Date Timestamp(3) NULL 
)
```

Error:

> ORA-01843: not a valid month

Thanks

Comment: I'm not an Oracle guy, but I _think_ `'31-AUG-2021 16:30:01.850'` perhaps can work.

Comment: Your code assumes a very specific value of the `nls_date_format` session variable. Does your application set it accordingly?

Comment: I have data script with these values only  '2021-08-31T16:30:01.850'.

Comment: Where does this value come from? If possible use timestamp parameters instead of strings

Answer (score 2):

Don't use strings when dealing with dates and timestamps.

```
'2021-08-31T16:30:01.850'
```

is a string. It contains a timestamp format that I remember I have seen in SQL Server.

The following is a valid timestamp literal, both in standard SQL and Oracle:

```
timestamp '2021-08-31 16:30:01.850'
```

Hence:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Account_Master (Account_ID, Verified_Date) 
VALUES (1, TIMESTAMP '2021-08-31 16:30:01.850')
```

Comment: Just a note, '2021-08-31T16:30:01.850' is a valid timestamp according to ISO 8601, the date/time standard. However, it's not valid a ISO SQL format.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't require the `T` separator either and works just fine with `2021-08-31 16:30:01.850'`.  Older versions of ISO8601 omitted the `T` separator but [since 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times) the `T` is required. Perhaps newer versions of Oracle can handle the current ISO8601 format as well?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The ISO standard for dates is ISO8601. The ISO standard for SQL is ISO/IEC 9075 which specifies the timestamp literal format as `TIMESTAMP '2011-07-01 00:00:00.000000000'` (fractional seconds are optional). If other RDBMS support `T` instead of a space in timestamp literals  then that is outside ISO9075 (regardless of whether it complies with a different ISO standard).

Comment: @MT0 no database product offers more than basic compliance with the SQL standard. Which isn't freely available. The quirks of the SQL standard are quite enjoyable and most of the time have nothing to do with standardization, everything to do with a vendor pushing their implementation on the others. And time is one area where the SQL committee would shame GoT. ISO8601 isn't just "some other ISO standard", it's the date literal supported by all languages and services

Answer (score 0):

> I have data script with these values only `'2021-08-31T16:30:01.850'`

Use `TO_TIMESTAMP` to explicitly convert from a string to a `TIMESTAMP` data type:

```sql
INSERT INTO tbl_Account_Master (Account_ID, Verified_Date) 
VALUES (1, TO_TIMESTAMP('2021-08-31T16:30:01.850', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3'));
```

---

You can also use implicit conversion (but this is not best practice) and alter the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` session parameter that Oracle will implicitly use as the format model for conversion from a string to a `TIMESTAMP` (when no explicit format model is given).

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3';
```

or, if you want to leave the precision of the fractional seconds ambiguous:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF';
```

Then your `INSERT` query would work (at least until the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` session parameter was changed to something else and then your query would break again ... which is why it is not best practice to rely on implicitly setting the conversion format).

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=77289e1aefaa0198548b54fb5591615f)*